# Create dropdown list jsf

Tags: jsf

Currently i'm stuck in create two dropdown list in jsf by click a "Add" button.

Initial i have a form with two dropdownlist, a "Add" button and a "submit" button.

The first dropdownlist is list country. The second dropdownlist is list city.

When user choose a country then the second dropdownlist will add dynamic city of this country(i done this using ajax f:ajax).

- how can i add two other dropdownlist(list country and list city also) when add button clicked?(it mean user can add a lot of pair dropdownlist using add button)
- how about structure of bean to manage all pair dropdownlist when i click submit button?

Please give me some example code to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `c:forEach`? Similar to the following:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{bean.numberOfAddsCLicked}" step="1">
    <!-- Your elements to repeat here. Probably bind their values to bean.country[i] respective bean.city[i] with country and city being arrays of bean.numberOfAddsCLicked -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's help me having more one solutions.